# References and redefined enumerate lists

Tags: cross-referencing, enumerate

I redefined `\theenumii`, which is fairly simple, but when I reference it in the text, the result of `\ref{enumi21}` below is 22.1, instead of 2.1.

If I redefine `\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}` as `\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}`, `\ref{enumi21}` outputs correcly as 2.1, but then of course the label is messy.

If, on the other hand, this solves the problem:

```
\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\arabic{enumi}.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{.\arabic{enumii}}
```

The text is OK, *but* `\theenumii` returns `.1` in the text. Of course I'll never need to use `\theenumii`, but I'd just like to understand the logic behind this.

```
\documentclass{article}


\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{enumi1}
\item Number 2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Number 2.1 \label{enumi21}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\ref{enumi1}, \ref{enumi21}.

\theenumii \verb|\theenumii|

\theenumi \verb|\theenumi|
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you try loading `enumitem` and adding  to your preamble: `\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}`?

Comment: @Bernard, It also works, but there's the same caveat: try `\theenumii` and the value returned will be `a`.

Comment: Without your modifications (only my suggestion)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,2]{label=\theenumi.\arabic*}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{enumii}{enumi}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{enumi1}
\item Number 2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Number 2.1 \label{enumi21}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
See \ref{enumi1}, \ref{enumi21}.

\theenumii \verb|\theenumii|

\theenumi \verb|\theenumi|

\end{document}
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to load `chngcntr`, replace `\counterwithin{…}` with this line:

```
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
```

Comment: Bernard, it makes sense to add `\counterwithin{enumii}{enumi}`, but isn't this already defined in the main classes? It seems that setting `\labelenumii` and `\theenumii` disrupts something inside the usual `\ref` argument, that's what I wanted to know.

Comment: What is defined in the standard classes is resetting enumii when enumi is increased. `\counterwithin`, additionally,   prepends the value of `enumi` to the value of `enumii` and add a dot in between.

Answer (score 0):

If you ask for the meaning of `\labelenumii` and `\theenumii`, you get

```
\labelenumii:
\long macro:->(\theenumii )

\theenumii:
\long macro:->\@alph \c@enumii
```

(I used `texdef`). If you ask for `\p@enumii`, you get

```
\p@enumii:
\long macro:->\theenumi
```

and this is the key to your problem. The macro `\p@enumii` is prepended to the value given by `\theenumii` when the label is being processed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\theenumi.\arabic{enumii}}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\arabic{enumii}}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@enumii}{\theenumi.}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item \label{enumi1}
\item Number 2
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Number 2.1 \label{enumi21}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\verb|\ref{enumi1}| $\to$ \ref{enumi1}.

\verb|\ref{enumi21}| $\to$ \ref{enumi21}.

\end{document}
```

[image]